# How to go from the joint probability mass function to the distribution function

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions

I need to solve the following math problem:

> The stochastic X and Y only take positive values. They have a common opportunity-density:
>   $$
>     f_{X;Y}(x; y) = 2e^{-x-2y}
> $$
>   Calculate the joint distribution function for x and y are bigger than or equal to 0.

What I tried is to take the double integral with respect to dx and dy. But according the manual that is the wrong aswers.

My aswers: Cy+e^(-x-2y)+C

The manuals answer: 1 - e^(-x) - e^(-2y) + e^(-x-2y)

I can't see yet what I did wrong.

If anybody could give me feedback,

Thanks in advance

Ter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F(x,y)=\int_0^{x}\int_0^{y} 2e^{-t-2s} dsdt=(\int_0^{x} e^{-t}dt)(\int_0^{y} 2e^{-2s}ds)$. This becomes $(1-e^{-x}) (1-e^{-2y})=1-e^{-x}-e^{-2y}+e^{-x-2y}$.